# issues with saveAssociated cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm having some issues trying to save an article that has 4 pictures. The thing is that i need to use the article id in order to name the pictures like `article_id."-"$i`

Since I have only 4 pictures per article this $i should be from 1 to 4 or from 0 to three.

Now the problem is that in order to achieve this i need to create and save Article model so i can have an id to use, but then after performing all the scripting to make the thumbs and form the names, when I go Article->saveAssociated() i have two times the article record created!! i tried to set the id to "-1" before saving but nothing...

Any suggestion will be very much appreciated !!!

**Code:**

```
public function add() {

    if ($this->request->is ( 'ajax' )) {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
    } else {
        $this->layout = 'default';
    }



    if ($this->request->is ( 'post' )) {

        $this->Article->create ();

        $this->request->data ['Article'] ['time_stamp'] = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', time () );  




        if ($this->Article->save($this->request->data) ) { 


        for ($i=0; $i<4; $i++){



            $img_path = "./images/";
            $extension[$i] = end(explode('.', $this->request->data['Image'][$i]['image']['name']));

            $this->request->data['Image'][$i]['image'] = array('name'=>$this->Article->id."-".$i,  'tmp_name' => $this->request->data['Image'][$i]['image']['tmp_name']);
        //  $this->request->data['Image'][$i]['name'] = $this->Article->id."-".$i;


            $this->request->data['Image'][$i]['ext']= $extension[$i];

            $target_path[$i] = $img_path . basename($this->request->data['Image'][$i]['image']['name'].".".$extension[$i]);


            if(!move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['Image'][$i]['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path[$i])) {

                die(__ ( 'Fatal error, we are all going to die.' ));

            }else{

                $this->Resize->img($target_path[$i]);
                $this->Resize->setNewImage($img_path.basename($this->request->data['Image'][$i]['image']['name']."t.".$extension[$i]));
                $this->Resize->setProportionalFlag('H');
                $this->Resize->setProportional(1);
                $this->Resize->setNewSize(90, 90);
                $this->Resize->make();

            }
            }


            $this->Article->id;
            pr($this->Article->id);
            $this->Article->saveAssociated($this->request->data, array('deep' => true));
            //$this->redirect ( array ('action' => 'view', $this->Article->id ) );
            pr($this->Article->id);
            exit;   
            $this->Session->setFlash ( __ ( 'Article "' . $this->request->data ["Article"] ["name"] . '" has been saved' ) );


        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash ( __ ( 'The article could not be saved. Please, try again.' ) );
        }

}



    $items = $this->Article->Item->find ( 'list' );
    $payments = $this->Article->Payment->find ( 'list' );
    $shippings = $this->Article->Shipping->find ( 'list' );

    $this->set ( compact ( 'items', 'payments', 'shippings' ) );
}
```

Comment: how can i get the futre id without previously saving ? is it possible? this why i wouldn't have this saved two times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$this->Article->saveAssociated();
```

which would save the Article AGAIN, just save the images separately using something like this:

```
foreach($this->request->data['Image'] as &$image) {
    $image['name'] = 'whatever_you_want' . $this->Article->id;
    $image['article_id'] = $this->Article->id;
}
$this->Article->Image->save($this->request->data['Image']);
```

Another option (not necessarily better - just another option) would just be to append the newly-created Article's `id` to the existing `Article` array, then `saveAssociated()`.  If the Article has an `id` in it's data, it will update instead of create.  I would suggest the first answer above, but - just brainstorming other options in case this helps for someone's scenario:

```
// 1) save the Article and get it's id
// 2) append the `id` into the Article array
// 3) do your image-name manipulation using the id
// 4) saveAssociated(), which updates the Article and creates the Images
```

Comment: let me ask you a question, what does the & sign does in that example? I will do it like you are saying, i dont think there is another approach for this one, thanks man

Comment: The ampersand (&) should make it so when you reference/append to the `$image` variable within the `foreach()` loop, it actually alters the `$data['Image']` array instead of just altering the temporary `$image` variable - which is what you want to do, since you're just appending to the existing data, then using it to save.